# What are the keyboard shortcuts of Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5, keyboard

What are the keyboard shortcuts in Civilization V?

Comment: Related: [this is how to change them](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/civilization-5-is-it-possible-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts of Civilization 5

#### General Hotkeys

```
F1         Civilopedia
F2         Economic info
F3         Military info
F4         Diplomacy info
F5         Social Policies Screen
F6         Tech Screen
F7         Notification Log
F8         Victory Progress
F9         Demographics
F10        Strategic View
F11        Quick Save
F12        Quick Load
G          Hex Grid
Esc        Menu
Enter      End Turn
Period     Next Unit
Comma      Previous Unit
-          Zoom Out
+          Zoom in
Insert     Capital City View
Home       Capital City View
End        Capital City View
Page Up    Zoom in
Page Down  Zoom Out
Ctrl+R     Show Resources Icons
Y          Yield Icons
Ctrl+O     Game Options
Ctrl+S     Save
Ctrl+L     Load
Ctrl+Space End Turn
```

#### General Unit Hotkeys

```
M          Move Mode
E          Explore (Automated)
A          Alert
F          Sleep
Space      Do Nothing
U          Upgrade unit (if in your own territory)
```

#### Action Hotkeys

```
Delete     Delete Unit
Ctrl+A     Attack
Ctrl+B     Ranged
S          Set up Artillery
H          Fortify Until Healed
```

#### Air Unit Hotkeys

```
Alt+R      Rebase Mode
S          Air Strike Mode
Alt+S      Air Sweep
I          Intercept
N          Nuke Mode
```

#### Civilian Unit Hotkeys

```
B          Found City
A          Build Improvements (automated)
R          Construct a Railroad
R          Construct a Road
Alt+R      Route to Mode
Alt+C      Remove a Jungle
Alt+C      Clear a Marsh
T          Construct a Trading Post
H          Construct a Camp
I          Construct a Farm
N          Construct a Mine
P          Construct a Plantation
Q          Construct a Quarry
P          Construct a Pasture
F          Construct a Fort
O          Create a Well
F          Create Fishing Boats
O          Create Offshore Platform
Alt+C      Remove Forest
Backspace  Cancel Last Mission
L          Construct a Lumber Mill
C          Citadel
```

Have fun =)

[SOURCE](http://segmentnext.com/2010/09/23/civilization-v-hotkeys-keyboard-shortcuts-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

Below is an image of the game shortcuts and options:

[image: Civilization 5 Shortcut from the internet]

Answer (score -1):

The above list is missing one:

```
V       Advisors
```

You can also change the key bindings in the XML file located at:

`<install location>\Sid Meier's Civilization V\Assets\Gameplay\XML\Units\CIV5Controls.xml`

Comment: Add a comment instead of another answer though