# Is there a way to bind "Buy a Tile" in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Using a x10 mod and playing as America, enabling me to buy tiles and gain money. Since I'm messing around with it, is it possible to bind "Buy a Tile" to a key?

Comment: Not sure if dupe... But https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/is-it-possible-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts