# What are the keyboard shortcuts for Civilization 5: Brave New World?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

So, there already exists a list of [keyboard shortcuts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/what-are-the-keyboard-shortcuts-of-civilization-5) for Civ 5 Vanilla. By pressing buttons I even found some extra ones:

> `V - Advisors Screen` 
>   `Alt+Q - Admit Defeat`

I have also found some shortcuts for Gods & Kings:

> `Ctrl+E - Espionage Screen` 
>   `Ctrl+P - Religion Screen`

But I still haven't found the shortcuts for the new Brave New World options - specifically:

> `? - Culture Overview Screen` 
>   `? - World Congress Screen` 
>   `? - Trade Routes Screen` 
>   `? - Show Trade Routes on map`

Any idea on what they are?

Comment: Didn't F1-F12 bring up the various advisors in the old games?

Comment: F1-F12 still work, but they bring screens/advisors that were already present in Civ5 vanilla. But I haven't found any keys to bring up the new ones (new to BNW).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found the answer, and it's disappointing.

Basically, **there are no shortcuts for the new BNW options**. This is easy to check: shortcuts for Brave New World are coded in

> \Sid Meier's Civilization V\assets\DLC\Expansion2\Gameplay\XML\Units\CIV5Controls.xml

which is exactly the same file as

> \Sid Meier's Civilization V\assets\DLC\Expansion\Gameplay\XML\Units\CIV5Controls.xml

which contained the shortcuts for Gods & Kings. Maybe they'll fix it in an upcoming patch, or maybe someone will figure out how to mod these shortcuts... But it's very frustrating for now.

Comment: Let me reiterate what they've said: CIV5Controls.XML is practically the same between G&K as BNW. Checked via textdiff.com. When I read this at first, I thought onuryn meant they're stored identically rather than their contents being identical.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source code for keyboard shortcuts with DLC (which only adds shortcuts to Espionage Overview and Religion Overview (in G&K) as you've found). I've modified it for readability. Taken from `\Sid Meier's Civilization V\assets\DLC\Expansion2\Gameplay\XML\Units\CIV5Controls.xml` as onuryn mentioned. Several do nothing, such as SELECTYUNITTYPE, NEXTUNIT, and PREVUNIT.

```
<Type>CONTROL_CENTERONSELECTION
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_CENTER_SELECTION
<HotKey>KB_C
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPAD5

<Type>CONTROL_SELECTYUNITTYPE
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SELECT_UNIT_TYPE
<HotKey>KB_C
<CtrlDown>1
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPAD5
<CtrlDownAlt>1

<Type>CONTROL_SELECTYUNITALL
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SELECT_UNIT_ALL
<HotKey>KB_C
<AltDown>1
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPAD5
<AltDownAlt>1

<Type>CONTROL_SELECTCITY
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SELECT_CITY
<HotKey>KB_INSERT

<Type>CONTROL_SELECTCAPITAL
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SELECT_CAPITAL
<HotKey>KB_F10
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_NEXTCITY
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_NEXT_CITY
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_NEXT_CITY_HELP
<HotKey>KB_HOME
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPADPLUS

<Type>CONTROL_PREVCITY
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_CITY
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_CITY_HELP
<HotKey>KB_END
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPADMINUS

<Type>CONTROL_NEXTUNIT
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_PLOT_UNIT_HELP
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_NEXT_UNIT_HELP
<HotKey>KB_PERIOD
<CtrlDown>1
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPADSTAR

<Type>CONTROL_PREVUNIT
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_PLOT_UNIT_HELP
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_PREVIOUS_UNIT_HELP
<HotKey>KB_COMMA
<CtrlDown>1
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPADSLASH

<Type>CONTROL_CYCLEUNIT
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_CYCLE_UNITS
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_CYCLE_UNITS_HELP
<HotKey>KB_W
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPADENTER

<Type>CONTROL_CYCLEUNIT_ALT
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_CYCLE_UNITS_ALT
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_CYCLE_UNITS_ALT_HELP
<HotKey>KB_PERIOD
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPAD5

<Type>CONTROL_CYCLEWORKER
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_CYCLE_WORKERS
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_CYCLE_WORKERS_HELP
<HotKey>KB_SLASH

<Type>CONTROL_LASTUNIT
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_LASTUNIT
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_LASTUNIT_HELP
<HotKey>KB_COMMA

<Type>CONTROL_ENDTURN
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_ENDTURN
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_ENDTURN_HELP
<HotKey>KB_RETURN
<HotKeyPriority>1</HotKeyPriority>
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPADENTER
<HotKeyPriorityAlt>1</HotKeyPriorityAlt>

<Type>CONTROL_ENDTURN_ALT
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_ENDTURN_ALT
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_ENDTURN_ALT_HELP
<HotKey>KB_SPACE
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_FORCEENDTURN
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_FORCE_ENDTURN
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_FORCE_ENDTURN_HELP
<HotKey>KB_RETURN
<ShiftDown>1</ShiftDown>
<HotKeyAlt>KB_NUMPADENTER
<ShiftDownAlt>1</ShiftDownAlt>

<Type>CONTROL_AUTOMOVES
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_AUTOMOVES
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_AUTOMOVES_HELP
<HotKey>KB_A
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_PING
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_PING
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_PING_HELP

<Type>CONTROL_YIELDS
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_YIELDS
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_YIELDS_HELP
<HotKey>KB_Y

<Type>CONTROL_RESOURCE_ALL
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_RESOURCE_ALL
<Help>TXT_KEY_GLOBELAYER_RESOURCES
<HotKey>KB_R
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_UNIT_ICONS
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_UNIT_ICONS
<Help>TXT_KEY_GLOBELAYER_UNITS
<HotKey>KB_U
<AltDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_SCORES
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SCORES
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SCORES_HELP

<Type>CONTROL_LOAD_GAME
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_LOAD_GAME
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_LOAD_GAME_HELP
<HotKey>KB_L
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_OPTIONS_SCREEN
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_OPTIONS_SCREEN
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_OPTIONS_SCREEN_HELP
<HotKey>KB_O
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_RETIRE
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_RETIRE
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_RETIRE_HELP
<HotKey>KB_Q
<AltDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_SAVE_GROUP
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SAVE_GROUP
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SAVE_GROUP_HELP
<HotKey>KB_S
<AltDown>1
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_SAVE_NORMAL
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SAVE_NORMAL
<Help>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SAVE_GAME_HELP
<HotKey>KB_S
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_QUICK_SAVE
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_QUICK_SAVE
<HotKey>KB_F11

<Type>CONTROL_QUICK_LOAD
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_QUICK_LOAD
<HotKey>KB_F11
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_CIVILOPEDIA
<HotKey>KB_F1

<Type>CONTROL_POLICIES_SCREEN
<Description>TXT_KEY_ACTION_SHOW_POLICIES_SCREEN
<HotKey>KB_F5

<Type>CONTROL_FOREIGN_SCREEN
<Description>TXT_KEY_FOREIGN_ADVISOR_TITLE
<HotKey>KB_F4

<Type>CONTROL_MILITARY_SCREEN
<Description>TXT_KEY_MILITARY_ADVISOR_TITLE
<HotKey>KB_F3

<Type>CONTROL_TECH_CHOOSER
<Description>TXT_KEY_TECH_CHOOSER_TITLE
<HotKey>KB_F6

<Type>CONTROL_TURN_LOG
<Description>TXT_KEY_EVENT_LOG
<HotKey>KB_F7

<Type>CONTROL_DOMESTIC_SCREEN
<Description>TXT_KEY_DOMESTIC_ADVISOR_TITLE
<HotKey>KB_F2

<Type>CONTROL_VICTORY_SCREEN
<Description>TXT_KEY_VICTORY_SCREEN_TITLE
<HotKey>KB_F8

<Type>CONTROL_INFO
<Description>TXT_KEY_INFO_SCREEN
<HotKey>KB_F9

<Type>CONTROL_SELECT_HEALTHY
<Description>TXT_KEY_MAIN_MENU_HALL_OF_FAME
<HotKey>KB_H
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_TOGGLE_STRATEGIC_VIEW
<Description>TXT_KEY_POP_STRATEGIC_VIEW
<HotKey>KB_F10

<Type>CONTROL_ADVISOR_COUNSEL
<Description>TXT_KEY_ADVISOR_COUNSEL_TITLE
<HotKey>KB_V

<Type>CONTROL_ESPIONAGE_OVERVIEW
<Description>TXT_KEY_EO_TITLE
<HotKey>KB_E
<CtrlDown>1

<Type>CONTROL_RELIGION_OVERVIEW
<Description>TXT_KEY_RELIGION_OVERVIEW
<HotKey>KB_P
<CtrlDown>1
```